# Pandas - add NaN for missing values when pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am concatenating all files in a directory together into one, however some files have a different number of entries - how to I place an NaN when there isn't a value for that key in the file?

For example:

file1.cs

```
 NUM, NAME, ORG, DATA
 1,AAA,10,123.4
 1,AAB,20,176.5
 1,AAC,30,133.5
```

file2. cs

```
 NUM, NAME, ORG, DATA
 1,AAA,10,111.4
 1,AAC,30,122.5
 2,BBA,12,156.7
```

Desired Output

```
 NUM, NAME, ORG, File1, File2 ....
 1, AAA, 10, 123.4, 111.4
 1, AAB, 20, 176.5, NaN
 1, AAC, 30, 133.5, 122.5
 2, BBA, 12, NaN,   156.7
 .....
```

This is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('analysis.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
data = []
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.cs", sep = ',', header = 'infer')    

for infile in glob.glob("*.cs"):
    df = pd.read_csv(infile, sep = ',', header = 'infer')
    name = infile[13:-7]
    df['filename'] = name
    data.append(df)
result = pd.merge(df1, data.to_frame(), on= 'NAME')
result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname)
writer.save()
```

I also tried `pd.concat(data, axis=1, ignore_index=False)` but this doesn't add the NaN because it just concatenates the files based on the column name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `merge` with parameter `how` equal to 'outer':

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['NUM','NAME','ORG'], how='outer')
```

Output:

```
   NUM NAME  ORG  DATA_x  DATA_y
0    1  AAA   10   123.4   111.4
1    1  AAB   20   176.5     NaN
2    1  AAC   30   133.5   122.5
3    2  BBA   12     NaN   156.7
```

To get your exact output use:

```
df1.rename(columns={'DATA':'FILE'})\
   .merge(df2.rename(columns={'DATA':'FILE'}), 
         on=['NUM','NAME','ORG'],
         how='outer', 
         suffixes=('1','2'))
```

Output:

```
   NUM NAME  ORG  FILE1  FILE2
0    1  AAA   10  123.4  111.4
1    1  AAB   20  176.5    NaN
2    1  AAC   30  133.5  122.5
3    2  BBA   12    NaN  156.7
```

Comment: Right, in my answer below, I had accidentally merged only on `'NUM'`, but you are totally correct...

Answer (score 1):

try something along the lines of this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.cs", sep = ',', header = 'infer')
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.cs", sep = ',', header = 'infer')
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['NUM','NAME','ORG'], how='outer')
```

you can read df2 in your loop however you want, but this would be the general syntax to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. Use `suffixes` argument to name your columns.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['NUM', 'NAME', 'ORG'], suffixes=('_FILE1', '_FILE2'))

#    NUM NAME  ORG  DATA_FILE1  DATA_FILE2
# 0    1  AAA   10       123.4       111.4
# 1    1  AAB   20       176.5         NaN
# 2    1  AAC   30       133.5       122.5
# 3    2  BBA   12         NaN       156.7
```